# Firebase Analytics - What to do with existing Google Analytics property

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I recently migrated to Firebase Analytics from Google Analytics for my app. Everything works fine, I access https://console.firebase.google.com/project/MYPROJECT/analytics/app/android:COM.MYPROJECT/overview to see my analytics.

Today I learned from https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6392697?hl=en that I can connect Firebase Analytics to Google Analytics.

Now I have duplicate data there (1st and 2nd row):

[image: GA screenshot]

**QUESTION: Can I safely delete the original (non-Firebase) property?** The reason I ask is, in my Firebase `google-services.json` file, the `Tracking Id` is the same with the original's.

Comment: Similarly, if you delete a Firebase property from Google Analytics, does it delete the Firebase project or just remove it from Google Analytics?

Comment: What is the Tracking Id in the .json file? I dont see that in my .json file that I got from Firebase. The way I setup my data so that its in GA is the use of GTM with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

@BFar If you delete the Google Analytics property associated with Firebase project, it will not delete the associated Firebase Project. You can try that by selecting the move to Trash Can, and the subsequent screen will have this notice.